# Accessing variable within results list

Tags: ansible

I'm looking to add a step to an existing playbook that will stop/fail on when it locates a specific directory, specified in var_file.yml

```
---
- include_vars:
    file: var_file.yml

- name: Check if instance has been Patched
  stat:
    path: '{{ item }}'
  register: patchDir
  loop: "{{ work_dir }}"

- fail: msg="This system has already been patched today!"
  loop: "{{ patchDir.results }}"
  when: (stat['exists'], true)
  loop_control:
    label: 'patchDir'
```

var_file.yml:

```
---
work_dir:
  - /var/tmp/patching_{{ansible_date_time.date}}
```

If I set path statically, rather than read it from `var_file.yml` then the following code works perfectly:

```
- name: Check if instance has been Patched
  stat:
    path: /var/tmp/patching_2020-06-10
  register: patchDir


- fail: msg="This system has already been patched today!"
  when: patchDir.stat.exists
```

Is there a way to retain the use of the variable defined in `var_file.yml` and make the first sample of code, work?

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what is not working exactly for you. Using a var in an `included_vars` file should work.  Your `when` seems odd though, I kind of feel it should have been `when: item.stats.exists`

Comment: Your input here has helped - the `when: item.stats.exists` was what I was look for (even though I didnt make a very good job of explaining it)! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So essentially I was trying to edit an existing playbook thats used for patching hosts and make it check if the host had already been patched (that day) by looking for the existence of variable defined in `var_file` `"{{work_dir}}"` and if it does exist - skip patching on this host.

Ended up with the following, which seems to work:

```
---
- include_vars:
    file: var_file.yml

- name: Check if for existance of patch dir
  stat:
    path: '{{ item }}'
  register: patchDir
  with_items: "{{ work_dir }}"

- name: Skip host if it has already patched today
  include_tasks: patch.yml
  loop: "{{ patchDir.results }}"
  when: not patch.stat.exists
  loop_control:
    label: "patchDir"
    loop_var: patch
```

The above will call task `patch.yml` if it finds a hosts that hasn't already been patched (that day) and patch it, otherwise skip it.

Possibly not the cleverest way to do it - but it seems to work :)